# Hewlett Packard hardware/Logitech mouse

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I need to use a touchpad, but I only have a desktop computer.  Touchpads seem to be only a laptop feature.

I have issues with "cramping index finger" after using the mouse a certain amount of time. When I don't use the mouse I don't have the problem. I am a senior and really enjoy my computer. I was told that I needed a "pad mouse"; I assume they were referring to a touchpad.

Is there a way to use a touchpad with a desktop computer?

Comment: "Pad mouse" refers to a touchpad, but desktops, don't have them

Comment: I know that but I was told at Costco today that there used to have some "pad mouse" instead of having to buy a laptop...do you know anything about this?

Comment: Costco isn't a great source of technical advice

Comment: @Ramhound these devices however, do exist

Answer (score 0):

Touchpads are built into laptops because they're thin, but you can get an add-on touchpad that plugs into a USB port on your desktop.  Amazon has a few.  Here's an [example of a basic model similar to what's in a laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007T27BE).

[image: touchpad]

It isn't clear what mouse action leads to your index finger cramping, but a touchpad might not be any better than a mouse because you use your finger for everything, especially if you tap rather than use the buttons (although you could switch to a different finger).

You may just want to experiment with different pointing devices to see what works best for you.  Try a touchpad.  If you've used one on a laptop, you already know your experience with it.

Another commonly used option is a trackball. There are lots of models.  I happen to use [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005T406).  (At one time, I used the touchpad above.)

If you have ready access to a computer store (or other store with a big computer department), they may have a lot of pointing devices on display.  Try them out to see what feels comfortable.  It may also be good to have a couple of different pointing devices.  If you find that long-term use of a particular one causes a problem, switch to a different one for awhile.